# How to send Images with some text in Local notification in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, uilocalnotification

In this code i have set all data those will show in my notification but how to set images in UILocal notification,I have tried to set images through `alertLaunchImage` but It doesn't work.

Here i have set all data of `UILocal notification`

```
-(void)ShowSelectedDate{

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = scheduleDatePicker.date;
localNotification.userInfo =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"_dateSelectionTextField.text", @"Time", @"/Users/GLB-285/Documents/learning-iOS/LatestautoLayoutApp/LatestautoLayoutApp/Assets.xcassets/food-1.imageset/food-1.png", @"image", nil];

localNotification.alertBody =@"Hei !!!!! Its done...Local Notification"  ;
localNotification.alertAction = @"alertAction";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
localNotification.alertLaunchImage=@"/Users/GLB-285/Desktop/f.png";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[self.dateSelectionTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*2ngvD9Tqp3TXjdWwVDMqEQ.jpeg

Comment: Please format your code: indentation, space placement, and don't make a mess. Why don't you say what's going wrong???

Comment: its Updated now,Please check and if something is missing then tell.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a string of filename of an image file present in the app's bundle. not image path. make sure image present in app bundle  (Note: It's name of the image, not an UIImage object)

Add f.png in your main bundle. then change the line to :

```
notification.alertLaunchImage = @"f.png";
```

Comment: No,Its not Working

Comment: got to Target > Build Phase > copy bundle resource
check f.png is exist on list. if f.png not on list add f.png using + .

Comment: Thanks..It has added to launch image ,But I want my image in attachment so that i can display it in my Local notification. I have added one image ,I want that things in my output.Please see.

Comment: check this tutorial hopefully it helps you : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251